# PreparedStatement gives two single quotes around string passed to setString

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have tried to recieve the maximum of a value in a column, using a preparedstatement. I get an error that one of the inputs to my function is read as ''table'' (double single quotes), instead of 'table'. I can't for the life of me understand why it would put the strings like that? Is there some special way to format the inputs to .setString()?

My function looks like this:

```
public static int getMax(String table, String column){
    //You'll have to replace this with your own connection if you want to try and run it
    try(Connection connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection();
        //This is the statement.
            PreparedStatement getMax = connection.prepareStatement("select max(?) from ?")){
            getMax.setString(1, column);
            getMax.setString(2, table);
            ResultSet max = getMax.executeQuery();
            if (max.next()){
                int m = max.getInt(1);
                try{
                    max.close();
                    return m;
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    System.out.println("SQL Error: Could not close max getter. " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else{
                try{
                    max.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    System.out.println("SQL Error: Could not close max getter. " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return -1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Other error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Most of this is error catching, but I hope the code is still readable.

I get this error:

```
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''resources'' at line 1
```

I've tried to look for answers all around, but no one seems to have answers for this exact question. Thank you for all responses. I apologize if this is a repost/duplicate of some kind.

Comment: You can't pass column and table names as parameters. Only values. The database needs to know the table and column names to prepare the query plan.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you! I could probably have found that out in the docs... Great help!